# Are there differences between pointers to object stored on stack and heap?

Tags: c, pointers, stack, llvm, heap-memory

Are there differences between pointers to object stored on stack and heap ? Are there internal representation in common C/C++ compilers (or JVM/LLVM) differs  ?

this is very interesting question somehow related to main : [memory location patterns on stack and heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857924/memory-location-patterns-on-stack-and-heap)

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19623603/1099142

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is a pointer. No matter *where* it points to.

I mean: you can assign to the same pointer both the address of a region *on the stack* and *on the heap*, don't you? So there cannot be any intrinsic difference between a pointer pointing here or there.

Answer (score -2):

The difference being ones on the stack you do not need to `free`